# Allocate variable type and size array inside function (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, void-pointers

I wish to create a `pointer` which means an array. The size and the type of the array (int, double, string etc..) is decided by a function, also the values. I've tried with `void**` but I got `segment error`.

```
char f(void** return_list){

    /*...*/

    /*If need integer array*/
    int int_input=1;         // for example
    int argument_number=2;       // for example

    return_variable=new void*[argument_number];
    for(int j=0;j<=argument_number;j++){
      return_variable[j]=new void*;
      *(int*)return_variable[j]=int_input;
    }

    /*If need boolean array*/
    /*...*/

return 0;
}

int main(int ARGC,char* ARGS[]){

char c=0; void** ret_list;
c=f(ret_list);
if(!c){std::cout<<*(int*)ret_list[0]<<"\n";}

return 0;}
```

**NOTE:**
I can't return the function `f()` with the array/pointer; I need to return with char/integer.

Comment: Your code has more stars than some of the hotels I had a misfortune of staying in. Use templates.

Comment: `argument number` -> undeclared identificer

Comment: @21koizyd : I've added `int argument_number`. Thanks the note.

Comment: Are you saying you want to write a function that creates an "array" (C-style) or a type and length to be decided at runtime?

Comment: Please post a complete program, which has the same problem. I've noticed one bug: at the for loop, `j<=argument_number` should be `j<argument_number`

Comment: In arguments you declared `return_list`, though you are allocating `return_variable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are 2 variants of the function. One is a fix of yours, which allocates an array of **void** pointers and then allocates a pointer to the data type of your interest. I think you intended it this way. You just need 3-star hotels there :-). This is kind of 'C'-style. You will ned to take special care of deleting all this later.

The second uses template in c++ style and just allocates an array of the type you are interested in:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void allocateArrayC(void ***array, int size) {
  *array = new void *[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    (*array)[i] =  new int(i);
}

template<class T>
void allocateArrayCPP(T **array, int size) {
  *array = new T[size];
  for (int  i = 0; i < size; i++)
    (*array)[i] = i;
}

int main () {
  void **arrayC;
  allocateArrayC(&arrayC, 10);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    cout <<  *(int*)arrayC[i] << endl;

  int *arrayCpp;
  allocateArrayCPP(&arrayCpp, 10);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    cout <<  arrayCpp[i] << endl;

}
```

Comment: BTW, you can simplify the syntax a bit, if you use references instead of pointers in arguments: `(void **&array)` or `(T *&array)` you can have `array[i] = ...` and `allocateArray(array, ...)`

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is a function that creates an array of size decided at runtime and initialize it to a certain value (since you are using `C++`) my suggestion is to use templates.

Something like the following should work:

```
template<typename TYPE>
TYPE* f(const TYPE input, const size_t SIZE) {
    TYPE* ret = new TYPE[SIZE];
    std::fill(ret,ret+SIZE,input);  
    return ret;
}
```

You can use it as in the following main:

```
int main()
{
    int size = 10;
    int initval = 2;

    int* p = f<int>(initval, 10);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << p[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    initval *= 2;
    size *= 2;
    double* q = f<double>(initval, size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << q[i] + 0.5f << " ";

    delete[] p;
    delete[] q;
}
```

which creates an array on `int` of size `10` and an array of size `20` of type `double` and print them on stdout.

```
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5
```

Plus, since you are using `C++` also consider to using raw pointers. Use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` instead.

Comment: You probably want to pass in the p or d as a parameter can retunr a char or int, to show how that's done s per the question, but +1 for C++ .

Answer (score 0):

If you want make something like I think that you schould use

```
void* return_variable = ::operator new[](argument_number);
```

or simpler use template or more specify specialization template.